# Jsonpickle - ensure deterministic encoding

Tags: python, serialization, deserialization, pickle, jsonpickle

The encoding is basically string representation of a dictionary, containing the object's fields. However, a dictionary does not respect order, and I could potentially get different encoding string on different runs. How do I preclude this from happening? Or should I use another library where I can ensure deterministic encoding?

By deterministic encoding, I mean if I create 100000 objects that are practically the same, i.e. same class and same constructor args, when I call `encode()` on each one of them, I get the exact same string every time.

So, for example, if I have

```
class MyClass(object):
   def __init__(self, a, b):
      self.a = a
      self.b = b

c1 = MyClass(1, 2)

c2 = MyClass(1, 2)
```

I want to be sure that the strings encode(c1) and encode(c2) are perfectly identical, character for character, i.e.

```
assert jsonpickle.encode(c1)==jsonpickle.encode(c2)
```

Comment: I do not understand,practically the same. Show us only 2 of your objects.

Comment: Please see my additional edit.

Answer (score 0):

I think that jsonpickle will take care of what you call determininstic endocing.

Example

```
import jsonpickle
class Monopoly(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.boardwalk_price = 500

    @property
    def boardwalk(self):
        self.boardwalk_price += 50
        return self.boardwalk_price



m = Monopoly()
serialized = jsonpickle.encode(m)
```

Take a look at

```
print (serialized)
{"py/object": "__main__.Monopoly", "boardwalk_price": 500}
```

Now, let's decode

```
d = jsonpickle.decode(serialized)
print (d)
<__main__.Monopoly object at 0x7f01bc093278>
d.boardwalk_price
500
```

For comparing objects,Python uses identifiers.

```
class MyClass(object):
   def __init__(self, a, b):
      self.a = a
      self.b = b

c1 = MyClass(1, 2)
c2 = MyClass(1, 2)
```

If you take a look at id

```
id(c1)
140154854189040
id(c2)
140154854190440
c1 == c2

False
```

You can override **eq** operator

```
def __eq__(self, x):
    if isinstance(x, number):
        return self.number == x.number
    return False
```

Comment: Note that the OP asks if the _encoding_ is exactly the same.  For core types like `str`, `bytes`, etc., if the contents are the same, the objects are equal: `"this".encode("utf-8") == "this".encode("utf-8") == b"this"`.  It is this _deterministic encoding_ that the OP specifically wanted verified.